# How do you add a score function and allow users to enter their names in Xcode game?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-input

I have created a tic tac toe game in `Xcode` but need help with **implementing a score board** and also **a function that shows the users name and current score**.

I have just got into `Xcode` and **I want to learn more**, would appreciate any help and suggestions. This is what I have done. I have added my whole code, thank you :)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var PlayerTurn = 1 //cross
    var BoardStatus = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
    var GameisActive = true
    let WinningCombos = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 6], [0, 4, 8], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if (BoardStatus[sender.tag-1] == 0 && GameisActive == true)
        {
            BoardStatus[sender.tag-1] = PlayerTurn

            if(PlayerTurn == 1)
            {
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "crossimage.png"), for: UIControlState())
                PlayerTurn = 2
            }
            else
            {
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "noughtimage.png"), for: UIControlState())
                PlayerTurn = 1
            }
        }

        for combination in WinningCombos
        {
            if BoardStatus[combination[0]] != 0 && BoardStatus[combination[0]] == BoardStatus[combination[1]] && BoardStatus[combination[1]] == BoardStatus[combination[2]]
            {
                GameisActive = false

                if BoardStatus[combination[0]] == 1
            {
                //cross wins
                print ("cross")
                Label.text = "CROSS HAS WON!"
            }
            else
            {
                //Nought has won
                print ("nought")
                Label.text = "NOUGHTS HAS WON!"

            }                
                PlayAgainButton.isHidden = false
                Label.isHidden = false

             }
    }
        GameisActive = false        
        for i in BoardStatus
        {
            if i == 0
            {
               GameisActive = true
               break
            }
       }          
        if GameisActive == false
        {
            Label.text = "It was a Draw!"
            Label.isHidden = false
            PlayAgainButton.isHidden = false
        }

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var PlayAgainButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func PlayAgain(_ sender: Any)
    {
        BoardStatus = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        GameisActive = true
        PlayerTurn = 1

        PlayAgainButton.isHidden = true
        Label.isHidden = true

        for i in 1...9
        {
            let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
            button.setImage(nil, for: UIControlState())
        }
    } 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 184/255, green: 184/255, blue: 184/255, alpha: 1)
     }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jay, welcome to SO. Can you please add some examples and error code of what you tried and describe the accompanying errors. If you do it helps solving your problem faster. Did you search for similar questions.. perhaps in different languages.. if so... inform us about it by editing your question. Not too much details in the comment section... as your question is not yet on par.

Comment: Hi, yes i have tried researching similar questions but have had no luck. I want the game to essentially start with both users entering their names and then play tic tac toe. Then whoever wins I want a score board to say who's winning and how many times they have won. unfortunately I don't know how to approach this in terms of writing out the code..

Answer (score 1):

To show current score just add a label in your storybard link it like you did with:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
```

advice: try to named less generic heheheh

After that just use .text property, but if you need the logic of this problem probably swift is not the topic you're looking for.

https://freecontent.manning.com/classic-computer-science-problems-in-swift-tic-tac-toe/